# Live data plotting lags after a while

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, matplotlib, pyqt

I've been writing a program for a workstation automation in a laboratory. One of the instruments I communicate is called beam profiler, it basically reads light inputs from two ortogonal directions (x,y). Once the input is read, I need to convert it to a 2D image, for that I use the numpy `meshgrid` and I'm able to obtain my desired output. 
For better clarity, see image bellow. The two Gaussian lines in the x and y axis are my raw input and the colored figure is after processed with meshgrid.
[image]

I divide my software in two parts for this. First I create another QT thread that initializes my device and runs in a loop getting the data and processing it. Then this thread sends a signal to the main thread with the values.

In the main thread I get the values, plot the graph and update the gui screen.

It is already working, the problem is that when I start the beam profiler readings the software starts getting slower as time passes. At first I thought it was because of the data processing but it doesn't make sense because it is running in the second thread and when I start the device there is no lag.
It seems like if it were "saving" the data in memory and getting slower, which is weird since I'm using the `set_data` and `draw` methods for plotting.

Note: if I close the device readings inside my software the lags stops and if I start it again, it starts good but then lags as time passes.

Any incoming help is much appreciated!

Data acquisition thread code:

```
class ThreadGraph(QtCore.QThread):
    _signalValues = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)
    _signalGraph = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray)
    _signalError = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    BEAMstatus = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadGraph, self).__init__(parent)
        self.slit = 0
        self.state = False

    #Thread starts
    def run(self):
        self.init() #Device initialization (Not relevant, therefore omitted)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        while self.state == True: #Thread loop (data acquisition)
            self.emitValues() #Fun to get the data and emit
            time.sleep(0.016)
            self.emitGraph() #Process data into 2D and emit
        try: #When while is over, terminate the thread
            self.beam.close(self.session)
        except RuntimeError as err:
            print err 
        self.quit()

    def emitGraph(self): #Use the data acquired to to generate 2D image and emit
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(self.slit_data_int[self.slit][0::10], self.slit_data_int[self.slit+1][0::10])
        zz = xx * yy

        self._signalGraph.emit(
            self.slit_data_pos[self.slit][0::10],
            self.slit_data_int[self.slit][0::10],
            self.slit_data_pos[self.slit + 1][0::10],
            self.slit_data_int[self.slit + 1][0::10],
            zz
            )


    def emitValues(self):
        try: #Try to get data from device (data is stored in calculation_result)
            self.slit_data_pos, self.slit_data_int, self.calculation_result, self.power, self.power_saturation, self.power_intensities = self.beam.get_slit_scan_data(self.session)
        except RuntimeError as err:
            self._signalError.emit(str(err))
            return
        else: #emit data to gui main thread
            self._signalValues.emit(
                self.calculation_result[self.slit].peakPosition, 
                self.calculation_result[self.slit + 1].peakPosition,
                self.calculation_result[self.slit].peakIntensity, 
                self.calculation_result[self.slit + 1].peakIntensity,
                self.calculation_result[self.slit].centroidPosition, 
                self.calculation_result[self.slit + 1].centroidPosition,
                self.calculation_result[self.slit].gaussianFitDiameter, 
                self.calculation_result[self.slit + 1].gaussianFitDiameter
                )
```

Main Gui code:

```
class BP209_class(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, vbox, slit25, slit5, peakposx, peakposy, peakintx, peakinty, centroidposx, centroidposy, mfdx, mfdy):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        #Initialize a bunch of gui variables
        self.matplotlibWidget = MatplotlibWidget('2d')
        self.vboxBeam = vbox
        self.vboxBeam.addWidget(self.matplotlibWidget)
        self.vboxBeam.addWidget(self.matplotlibWidget.canvastoolbar)
        #Create the thread and connects
        self.thread = ThreadGraph(self)
        self.thread._signalError.connect(self.Error_Handling)
        self.thread._signalValues.connect(self.values_update)
        self.thread._signalGraph.connect(self.graph_update)
        self.thread.BEAMstatus.connect(self.Status)


        #Initialize variables for plots
        self.zz = zeros([750, 750])
        self.im = self.matplotlibWidget.axis.imshow(self.zz, cmap=cm.jet,  origin='upper', vmin=0, vmax=1, aspect='auto', extent=[-5000,5000,-5000,5000])
        self.pv,  = self.matplotlibWidget.axis.plot(np.zeros(750) , np.zeros(750) , color="white" , alpha=0.6, lw=2)
        self.ph,  = self.matplotlibWidget.axis.plot(np.zeros(750) , np.zeros(750), color="white" , alpha=0.6, lw=2)
        self.matplotlibWidget.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.00, bottom=0.01, right=0.99, top=1, wspace=None, hspace=None)
        self.matplotlibWidget.axis.set_xlim([-5000, 5000])
        self.matplotlibWidget.axis.set_ylim([-5000,5000])

    def __del__(self): #stop thread  
        self.thread.state = False
        self.thread.wait()

    def start(self): #start thread
        if self.thread.state == False:
            self.thread.state = True
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            self.thread.state = False
            self.thread.wait()

    #Slot that receives data from device and plots it
    def graph_update(self, slit_samples_positionsX, slit_samples_intensitiesX, slit_samples_positionsY, slit_samples_intensitiesY, zz):
        self.pv.set_data(np.divide(slit_samples_intensitiesX, 15)-5000, slit_samples_positionsX)
        self.ph.set_data(slit_samples_positionsY, np.divide(slit_samples_intensitiesY, 15)-5000)
        self.im.set_data(zz)
        self.im.autoscale()
        self.matplotlibWidget.canvas.draw()
```

Edit: I also have a camera attached to my system and I display it also in the gui using opencv. I noticed that if I start the cam the beam profiler's fps reduce to almost a half. So, maybe a QT paint optimization would be the way to go?

Comment: TL;DR. But, *if I close the device [...] lags stops and if I start it again, it starts good but then lags as time passes* sounds like the drawing code cannot keep up with the data acquisition rate and so a buffer fills up more and more. How often do you try to update the image?

Comment: I use a slot function for update. So whenever the acquisition and processing is done a signal is emitted. Then a slot in the main thread starts and handle the image update

Comment: Does not matter how you trigger the update. If, for example, you record data every 1ms and drawing takes 2ms what do you think will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to `canvas.draw()` are expensive. You are likely acquiring data faster than drawing commands can complete. This will cause paint events to get queued up and your plot will appear to lag. This [blog post](http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html) details a method that avoids calling `canvas.draw()` and can be used to speed up matplotlib realtime plotting.

If this is still not fast enough you may have to lower the acquisition rate, implement some form of frame skipping mechanism or use a different plotting library better optimised for speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it seems it fixed the issue. I'm just doing more tests to see if it really solved the problem but I guess it did! Much appreciated

Comment: Update: After more tests I've realized that it didn't fix the problem. I added a fps counter to the plot and I noticed that before I had around 10fps and with the changes I get around 14fps. It is still not enough. Maybe should I go to other library instead matplotlib?

Comment: Matplotlib is more focused on creating publication quality figures than performance. Try taking a look at something like [`PyQtGraph`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) which was written with speed in mind. If that's still slow, maybe you have other issues.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the PyQtGraph module but  it increased my fps to over 200! Quite impressive I must say! Thank you a lot for your advice.